# Class as instance vs Class definition | Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, factory-pattern, factory-method

By default, typescript rightfully infers a class type as an *instance* of said class rather than the class *definition* itself. I recently came across this distinction when refactoring a class factory method.

My question is what is the best way to indicate that an argument or type is an instance of the class or the *callable* definition of the class?

Take for example this class

```
class MyClass implements IMyClass {
  foo = 'foo';
  bar() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

Now I have two functions, the first `callBar` is expecting an instance of the class

```
function callBar(instance: MyClass) {
  return instance.bar();
}
```

The second `classFactory` is expecting the class definition.

```
function classFactory(MyClassDefinition: MyClass) {
  return new MyClassDefinition();
}
```

The problem is that this second function throws a type error

```sh
(parameter) MyClassDefinition: MyClass
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'MyClass' has no construct signatures.(2351)
```

The solution I resorted to was to use the `Class` type from [`utility-types`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#classt) npm package. which is defined as...

```
type Class<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function classFactory(MyClassDefinition: Class<MyClass>) {
  return new MyClassDefinition();
}
```

Is there a clearer, better or easier way of making this distinction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate it as a constructor type:

```
function classFactory(MyClassDefinition: new () => MyClass) {
  return new MyClassDefinition();
}
```